# How do I resolve a Axios Network Error I get when Developing a Microsoft Outlook AddIn?

Tags: axios, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have been getting this Axios Network Error for an Add-In I am trying to develop for Microsoft Outlook. I am using React and Typescript [Axios Network Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ieID.png)

The API I use works when tested via Curl or Postman with no CORS errors but when I call the same API in my program I get this error.

[API Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRBn9.png)

Comment: Just FYI, this has nothing to do with `Office-JS`, test making API calls in an HTML webpage to debug.

Answer (score 0):

The same-origin policy enforced by the browser or webview control prevents a script loaded from one domain from getting or manipulating properties of a webpage from another domain. This means that, by default, the domain of a requested URL must be the same as the domain of the current webpage. For example, this policy will prevent a webpage in one domain from making `XmlHttpRequest` web-service calls to a domain other than the one where it is hosted.

Because Office Add-ins are hosted in a web-view control, the same-origin policy applies to script running in their web pages as well.

The same-origin policy can be an unnecessary handicap in many situations, such as when a web application hosts content and APIs across multiple subdomains. There are a few common techniques for securely overcoming same-origin policy enforcement. The [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations) article provides the briefest introduction to some of them.